# What's the inverted form of 'If we had LeBron on our team too, we would’ve won'?

Tags: conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

I have a question regarding a sentence,  which goes:

> If we had LeBron on our team too, we would’ve won.

Context:

Reporter:

> “Coach said that, maybe if you guys had a little more time things might’ve been different,” the reporter asked. “Do you feel as though that might have been the issue?”

DeRoxan:

> “**If we had LeBron on our team too, we would’ve won**,” said an exasperated DeRozan. “We can say that all day. Time, everything, but we didn’t. It happened. We got swept and it’s going to be one of them long summers for us.”

Can the inversion be written as this:

> Had we have Lebron on our team too, we would have won.

I am quite acquainted with inverted sentences like ==> Had I known or Had I seen, but "Had we have" seems awkward to me. Please, shed light on this guys!

Comment: It is awkward because it should be "Had we **had** Lebron..." and the base sentence should be "If we **had had** Lebron on our side...".

Comment: Can't we have " Had we had Lebron "  for the base sentence "if we had  Lebron ... "  ?   Because This base sentence was actually spoken by DeRozan against his match with Lebron's team

Comment: The correct formulation, "Had we had Lebron...", doesn't sound too awkward to me. If it bugs you, you might reword it as "Had Lebron been on our side..." or "Had Lebron been playing for us..." or "With Lebron on our side..." with little change in meaning.

Comment: @Sharma Hi. Is there a video or audio that you can link to in which one can hear the original sentence?

Comment: @Clare ....  yes ofcourse see this @0:18    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAss0091s_c

Comment: Why do you think we should use a *have* in the inverted form of the sentence?

Answer (score -1):

No, your tenses are different.  It would need to be 'Had we had Lebron....' if you want that form of sentence. And strictly I think your first example needs to be 'If we had had Lebron', or 'If we'd had Lebron'.

Comment: But that's not what the 'first example', i.e., the original sentence,  was. We're dealing with real English here, not with what people think it needs to  be.